# NestedScrollView is not working with viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

In my activity I am using `Tablayout` bellow 300dp from the top is set. in Tablayout I have 3 fragments, the problem is it's showing the fragments but my layout is not scrolling up. I tried `Scrollview` and `NesterScrollview`, but none of them worked. please see my xml code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="260dp"
                android:background="#fff">
                 <!-- Cover Image -->

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bgimage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/profilebg" />

                <!-- Round image -->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/shareicon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:tint="@color/black"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/imageborder"
                    android:src="@drawable/share"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:elevation="12dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:innerRadius="0dp"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:thicknessRatio="1.9">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilepic"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/editic"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:tint="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/imageborder"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pencil"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#fff">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/usertitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tom Cruise"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/userlocation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Syracuse, New York"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:background="@color/material_purple_500"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="256"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="LIKES"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/material_purple_500"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    >

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2,080"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="FOLLOWERS"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/material_purple_500"/>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="144"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="FOLLOWING"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:background="@color/material_purple_500" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                style="@style/NavigationTab"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/ptab_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="260dp"
                android:background="#fff">
                 <!-- Cover Image -->

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bgimage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/profilebg" />

                <!-- Round image -->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/shareicon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:tint="@color/black"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/imageborder"
                    android:src="@drawable/share"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:elevation="12dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:innerRadius="0dp"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:thicknessRatio="1.9">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilepic"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/editic"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:tint="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/imageborder"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pencil"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#fff">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/usertitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tom Cruise"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/userlocation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Syracuse, New York"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:background="@color/material_purple_500"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="256"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="LIKES"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/material_purple_500"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    >

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2,080"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="FOLLOWERS"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/material_purple_500"/>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="144"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="FOLLOWING"
                        android:textSize="12sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:background="@color/material_purple_500" />

             <include layout="@layout/profile_tab_layout"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and included layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            style="@style/NavigationTab"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/ptab_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**IMAGE**[image]

this result is second approach using include. its showing tab's and fragments also, but if we scroll top rest of the content will show.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-viewpager-nestedscrollview-bukhori-aqid

Comment: please see my another approach. still Scrolling is not working

Comment: Viewpager with NestedScrollView  not possible only one solution set  ViewPager fixed height

Comment: i am not stick with NestedScrollView, please see my second approach

Comment: Can you post an image of your expected output?

Comment: ya i just added the result image please see the profile should go up and it should show the rest of the tab content

Comment: use coordinator layout
Check this Link : https://inducesmile.com/android-tips/android-coordinatorlayout-and-collapsingtoolbarlayout-tutorial/

Comment: that is only thing i can do now.